# How to get the coordinates of mouse click on a slice of pie-chart : Amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to get the coordinates of the mouse click on the amcharts pie-chart's slice. It is working for the whole page except the slices. event.pageX and event.clientX are not working, returning undefined. I want the coordinates with respect to the page.

```
{
    "event": "pullOutSlice",
    "method": function (event) {
                var relX = event.pageX;
                var relY = event.pageY;
   }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/6w78zmo9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ? 
https://jsfiddle.net/6w78zmo9/1/

Try this:

```
 var relX = event.chart.mouseX;
 var relY = event.chart.mouseY;
```

Comment: At first place, i thought it is giving the position of mouse click relative to the document but it is giving relative to the div only. I need position with respect to body not the chart div.

Comment: you can do some math, like adding left and top position of div (respective to body) to the co-ordinates that you are getting.